# Simple way to detect unused properties keys?

Tags: java, properties

Given a set of properties files and list of files which may reference keys in those properties files, what's the easiest way to determine which keys are unused?

Example:

Given a project with files

*muppets.properties*

```
kermit=Kermit the Frog
oscar=Oscar the Grouch
```

*smurfs.properties*

```
papa=Papa Smurf
```

and */WEB-INF/pages/template.jsp*

```
Some jsp template displaying the key <bean:write bundle='muppets' key='kermit'/>.
```

then running program with inputs "*.properties" and "/WEB-INF/**/*.jsp" should report

```
Unused properties:

muppets.properties
oscar

smurfs.properties
papa
```

What's the simplest way to do this? Are there any open-source Java libraries that make this easy? The idea is to embed the solution inside an in-house Maven reporting plugin that would run when building a web app.

I'm aware that there will be false positives (key strings appearing in the files in a non-key context), but that's ok. Being able to find any unused keys would be helpful.

Edit: I'm seeking a standalone code-base solution.

Comment: See also this question: [The Halting Problem in the field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235984/the-halting-problem-in-the-field)

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA has this functionality. Unfortunately is it used within the app and not as a Maven plugin.

Some of the modules in IDEA are open source. Many plugins are available to the community. Perhaps you could peek at their website to see if there is anything you can grab.

I hope this helps http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/index.jspa

Comment: Another great reason why IntelliJ is the best IDE there is, hands down.  (No, I don't work for them, and I don't get paid to say nice things.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm in an Eclipse/RAD environment so this isn't a viable alternative for me. Thanks though!

Comment: @duffymo. He he I would like to get paid for saying nice things about Idea. A license could do the work too ;)

Comment: How does that feature work? In many cases, which properties you use are decided at runtime.

Comment: The way that work is to look at your code ( all of the available code in the project ) and see if you're using the "key" of the property. If you don't the analyzer marks it as "unused". Pretty much the same way it does with any other variable.

Comment: and how do you do it using ItelliJ?

Comment: @jpganz18 it works out of the box for me. I'm not sure.

This is the doc I've found https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/properties-files.html?origin=old_help

Answer (score 0):

I think that JInto can help you.

http://www.guh-software.de/jinto_en.html