# Eclipse plugin to find out unused methods in a class/package

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am looking out for an eclipse plug-in that could be used to detect unused methods or classes across a project. Does any one know a efficient good to use plug-in of that kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like EclEmma (http://www.eclemma.org/) might be what you're looking for. It shows code coverage for packages, classes, methods and individual lines.

Some lines will never get 100% coverage (e.g. Enums) but it will give you a good idea about what's being used.

Comment: assuming you have a comprehensive test suite or manually run the code each time

Answer (score 15):

- [**Findbugs**](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) (which has an eclipse plugin) can show you "dead code" (through the [CalledMethods](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/detect/CalledMethods.html) detector)
- [UCDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/index.html) also provide that kind of feature

[image]

Of course, any of those tools can **NOT** deterministically find unused code (see the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). Any code could *eventually* be called, through various means like Reflection.
But those static analysis tools can help.
For additional hints, a good test coverage is still required (dynamic analysis).